# datatables.net get row data on row click

Tags: jquery, datatable

I have created datatable from datatable.net plugin. datatable generated in right way, but further I want to get the data of clicked row, How should i get?
Thank you in advance for your help.

here is the link which i referred to create datatable. http://datatables.net

here is my datatable code

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
        "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'T><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
        "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
        "oLanguage": {
            "sLengthMenu": "_MENU_ records per page"
        },
        "bProcessing": true,
                    "sAjaxSource": "server/product_status_get_data.php", //setting the server source here
                    "aoColumns": [
            { "mData": "prd_name" },
            { "mData": "total_doc" },
            { "mData": "promoted" },
             { "mData": "prescribed" }
        ],
        "oTableTools": {
            "aButtons": [
                "pdf"
            ]
        }           
    } );
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See sample : http://jsfiddle.net/WapYa/1/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $('#example td').live('click', function() {
    var anOpen = [];
    var nTr = this.parentNode;
    var i = $.inArray(nTr, anOpen);
    console.log(this); // clicked cell
    console.log(nTr); // clicked row
    $(this).parent().find("td").each(function() {
        console.log($(this).html()); // logs each cell value
    });
 });
});​
```

Comment: It worked A.V., Thank you very much. I checked the log in firebug. for peoples who want to check it in alert box just put this line alert($(this).html()); below console.log($(this).html());

Comment: keep going bro, all the best.

Comment: Can i get complete row data once, it is giving cell wise.

Comment: If you need the whole data as a single string (say comma separated), then declare a new `var` variable and append data to it  in the `.each()` function...